# Finding a homeomorphism between these two balls

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $u_1,u_2,u_3 \in \Bbb C$ be the cubic roots of unity.

Define two norms on $\mathbb{C}^2$,  $$\Vert (x,y) \Vert_1 = \sqrt{\vert x \vert^2 +\vert y \vert^2} \ \text{and} \ \Vert (x,y) \Vert_2 = \text{max}\lbrace \vert x + u_1y \vert, \vert x +u_2 y \vert, \vert x + u_3y \vert \rbrace.$$

I'd like to find an explicit homeomorphism between the unit balls in these norms.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I might proceed?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you considered any cases, corresponding to different regions of the plane?

Comment: I showed that the unit balls in $\Bbb R^2$ corresponding to $\Vert (x,y) \Vert_1 = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2} \ \text{and} \ \Vert (x,y) \Vert_2 = \text{max}\lbrace \vert x + y \vert, \vert x -y \vert \rbrace$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: Did your proof involve constructing an explicit map?

Comment: I showed that $\lbrace \left( x, y \right) : \text{max}\lbrace \vert x + y \vert,\vert x - y \vert \rbrace \leq 1 \rbrace = \lbrace \left( x, y \right) : \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert \leq 1 \rbrace$ and assumed from there that it was easy.

Comment: Doesn't $x\mapsto \frac {x||x||_2}{||x||_1}$ always give a continuous map with inverse $y\mapsto \frac {y||y||_1}{||y||_2} $ ?